# Store data globally from one controller to another using service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to display ajax response from one controller to another
This is controller 1

```
app.controller("currentTaskCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, currentTaskService) {

    $scope.currentTaskTab = function() {
    $http({
            url: '/index/tasktimer',
            method: 'POST',        
            data : {"currentTask": "current"},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}
        }).success(function(response) {                 
                currentTaskService.saveData(response.task_name, response.estimated_hours, response.time_remaining, response.start_date, response.stop_date, response.actual_hours);
            }).error(function(response) {
                $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed"
            });         
    }         
});
```

This is controller 2

```
app.controller("currentTaskTabCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, currentTaskService) {

    $rootScope.$on('currentTaskService', function() {
        $scope.data = currentTaskService.getData();
    });
});
```

This is service

```
app.service('currentTaskService', function($rootScope) {
    this.saveData = function(tname, estimated_hours, time_remaining, start_date, stop_date, actual_hours) {
        // Here the data gets saved in $rootScope.data
    }

    this.getData = function() {
        return data;
    }
});
```

This is HTML code (controller 2) where data gets displayed

```
<div ng-controller="currentTaskTabCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> # </th>
        <th> Task Name </th>
        <th> Estimated Hours </th>
        <th> Time Remaining </th>
        <th> Start Date </th>
        <th> Stop Date </th>
        <th> Actual Time </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="task in data">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{task.task_name}}</td>
        <td>{{task.estimated_hours}}</td>
        <td>{{task.time_remaining}}</td>
        <td>{{task.start_date}}</td>
        <td>{{task.stop_date}}</td>
        <td>{{task.actual_time}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this:

1- inject **$rootScope** to both of your controllers

2- implement below code to one of them as a data receiver:

```
$rootScope.$on('transferDataEvent', function(event, data) {
    // you will receive data here
  });
```

3- and for another call below code as a data sender

```
$rootScope.$emit('transferDataEvent', data); // send data
```

**$on** makes a listener and
 **$emit** dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data from controller as well.

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <button ng-click="sendData();"></button>
 </div>
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
        function sendData($scope) {
            var arrayData = [1,2,3];
            $rootScope.$emit('someEvent', arrayData);
        }
    });
    app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
            console.log(data); 
        }); 
    });
 </script>
```